# Uninstalling apache2

Tags: raspbian, apache-httpd

I have a Raspberry pi 3 B. I currently have apache2 installed in /usr/sbin/apache2. I cannot remember if I installed this myself - I don't remember doing so - but perhaps I did, since it is located in /usr/sbin and not /usr/bin.

I tried to configure apache2 as part of a project and messed things up and I would now like to uninstall it.

I tried doing the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

This appears to work, the output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pix-icons pix-plym-splash pixel-wallpaper
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  php5-cgi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2* libapache2-mod-php5*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-cgi
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,885 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,389 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main php5-cgi armhf 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7 [1,885 kB]
Fetched 1,885 kB in 0s (3,847 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php5-cgi.
(Reading database ... 122501 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php5-cgi_5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking php5-cgi (5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
dpkg: libapache2-mod-php5: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 php5 depends on libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7~) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7~) | php5-cgi (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7~) | php5-fpm (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7~); however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php5 is to be removed.
  Package libapache2-mod-php5filter is not installed.
  Package php5-cgi is not configured yet.
  Package php5-fpm is not installed.

(Reading database ... 122513 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7) ...
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module json for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysql for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module pdo_mysql for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysqli for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module readline for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module pdo for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module opcache for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module xcache for apache2 SAPI
Module php5 disabled.
apache2_invoke prerm: Disable module php5
Purging configuration files for libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7) ...
apache2_invoke postrm: Purging state for php5
Removing apache2 (2.4.10-10+deb8u16) ...
Purging configuration files for apache2 (2.4.10-10+deb8u16) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing apache2, directory '/var/www/html' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Setting up php5-cgi (5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u7) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php5-cgi to provide /usr/bin/php-cgi (php-cgi) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 to provide /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php (php-cgi-bin) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module json for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module readline for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module opcache for cgi SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module xcache for cgi SAPI
```

I'm confused, because apache2 appears to still be there.. When I look into /usr/sbin for apache, I can still find a file:

```
$ ls -l /usr/sbin/apache2

# Output:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 515808 Sep 30 23:34 /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Similary, I can do:

```
 $ which apache2
 # Output: 
 /usr/sbin/apache2
```

My question is: has my uninstallation worked? Why do I still have files? How can I be sure I have gotten rid of everything? I will most likely re-install apache2 at some point so I want to make sure it's all done properly.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be running an obsolete OS. Just start again with a supported OS.

Comment: Looks OK. Although you're clearly running an OS that's not Raspbian Buster (which has Apache2 and PHP7). So you may want to start building a new system based off Raspbian Buster rather than hacking at your old stuff.

Comment: *"but perhaps I did, since it is located in /usr/sbin and not /usr/bin"* -> You have the purpose of `/usr/local/bin` confused with `/usr/sbin`.   The latter is a totally normal place for distro packaged executables to go.  Notice it is full of them.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: This isn't really worth pursing unless you have a concrete reason to want apache gone -- besides the fact that you won't be using it.   If you disable the service it will not use any system resources, and notice above removing it will actually use *more* SD card space, although either way the amount is very very trivial.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks but let's say I want to install it again, can I just use "sudo apt-get install apache2" and expect all files to be placed where they used to be in /usr/sbin? In other words, have I broken anything? Or is it just that I somehow have some residual files that result in /usr/sbin when I do "which apache2"? I'm just worried I shouldn't have tried uninstalling apache2..

Comment: It sounds like it didn't uninstall properly, so I don't know what impact that would have -- I'd hope it would still reinstall without problems.  You can always try it, that shouldn't do any harm.